# Character recognition ML models

Tags: machine-learning

I hope I can make my question clear.

So I'm working on a machine learning project just for the sake of it (3rd year undergrad in CS) over our summer vacation.

So I'd like to recognize letters from common fonts. I downloaded my data set from chars74k dataset

http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/CVSSP/demos/chars74k/ (link to the dataset)

What I've done up until now:

I cleaned up the images a bit, resized the images, cleaned them from noise, resized them to be 32x32 etc. (also deleted some poor fonts that were not correct such as capital letters categorized as small letters etc).

Now to my problem: I'm trying to find a model that has a high test accuracy (as far as im concerned I don't mind overfitting the data because I only want to deal with fonts, so if I can categorize these fonts correctly I'll probably be alright on the majority of common fonts)

In any case the first model ive tried is KNN over HoG features of the letters, playing around a bit with stride and number of bins the best Ive managed so far is 87.3% accuracy.

So I'd like some advice on what other ML models would work, I'm looking in to CNNs and SVMs right now but can't find any literature on useful architectures. So can some expert offer me any advice?